# how long does it take to query specific variable in specific smart contracts storage in ethereum public blockchain

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, web3.py, frontend

my project is building Dapp for supplychain using public ethereum ( public ethereum ledger have huge data ) my question is if i deploy the backend in the blockchain so lets say that the frontend have page that you can write data ( name = string , walletadd = address , info = string ) , after that this input will be saved in the blockchain , now another user have other front page that contain a view function which use web3 to call those newly written variable , how long do it take for the web3 to find that smart contract hash and then search for the variable by name inside that smart contracts , is it instantly ? , does it take time to search ns,ms,s,mn ? i have direct connection to a blockchain node

thanks for you help in advance

Comment: You can get an idea of the times by using existing popular applications like dex, or similar. It is not instant, but it is quite fast.

Comment: so i used a sepolia to test it , i declared a struct 
 // set function update the struct information
// get function view the struct information

using remix ethereum injected web3 , and the SET function took 27 sc but the get function took 0.63 sc , so it quick